# Get duplicate set

Tags: sql, t-sql

I am trying to update a table with a duplicate set ID, based on the email address. I was able to find the duplicates using this query:

```
;WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT 
      [First Name]
    , [Last Name]
    , [E-mail Address]
    , ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY [E-mail Address] ORDER BY [First Name] ) RN
    FROM Contact_Master
)
SELECT * FROM CTE
```

Which gives me a table like so:

```
First Name    Last Name    Email Address         RN
-----------------------------------------------------
John          Doe          John.Doe@gmail.com    1
John          Doe          John.Doe@gmail.com    2
Jane          Doe          Jane.Doe@gmail.com    1
Jane          Doe          Jane.Doe@gmail.com    2
```

What i want is to have the RN field be a unique ID for each found duplicate:

```
First Name    Last Name    Email Address         RN
-----------------------------------------------------
John          Doe          John.Doe@gmail.com    1
John          Doe          John.Doe@gmail.com    1
Jane          Doe          Jane.Doe@gmail.com    2
Jane          Doe          Jane.Doe@gmail.com    2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it this way, by using DENSE_RANK:

```
;WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT 
      [First Name]
    , [Last Name]
    , [E-mail Address]
    , DENSE_RANK() OVER ( PARTITION BY [E-mail Address] ORDER BY [First Name] ) RN
    FROM Contact_Master
)
SELECT * FROM CTE
```

-- 
Owainrun this below:

```
with Contact_Master as
(
select 1 as id, 'John'   as [First Name]   ,     'Doe'  as [Last Name],        'John.Doe@gmail.com'  as [E-mail Address]  
union select 2, 'John'   ,       'Doe'   ,       'John.Doe@gmail.com'  
union select 3, 'Jane'   ,       'Doe'    ,      'Jane.Doe@gmail.com'   
union select 4, 'Jane'    ,      'Doe'    ,      'Jane.Doe@gmail.com'   
), CTE AS (
    SELECT id,
      [First Name]
    , [Last Name]
    , [E-mail Address]
    , DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY [Last Name] ORDER BY [E-mail Address] ) RN
    FROM Contact_Master
)
SELECT * FROM CTE
```

Output:

```
id  First Name  Last Name   E-mail Address  RN
3   Jane    Doe Jane.Doe@gmail.com  1
4   Jane    Doe Jane.Doe@gmail.com  1
1   John    Doe John.Doe@gmail.com  2
2   John    Doe John.Doe@gmail.com  2
```

Comment: That returns all with RN 1. Looks like taking out the `PARTITION` fixes that issue though. Thankyou!

Comment: I have added in my response a secund that will yield the result you want Owain. Hope it helps